# SourceTree did not download all files?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

For what reason when I do the first Fetch, this one did not download all files? That is, in the main computer there are 17000 files, but when I do the Fetch, just download 12000. What we are not download pictures and some important files (php files). Do you know what can be the reason? What must I do to be downloaded and sync all files?

Comment: Are some of your files ignored? Are they present in a different branch?

Comment: No, we work with the same branch, and yes, some of my files are ignored and did not download :-(

Comment: I mean that they're formally ignored by Git, by matching patterns in `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: I dont know, how I can see if this files are ignored for Git? or how I can do for this files are not ignored?

Comment: If the files are ignored, Git has no knowledge of them at all. That's the point of ignoring files. They won't be versioned, Git doesn't care if they're modified or deleted, and they won't be included in `push`es or `fetch`es (both of these commands work with *commits*, not files). To see if a file is ignored, and by which pattern, run `git check-ignore -v path/to/file` on the "main computer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the SourceTree devs. Whilst SourceTree might seem to be doing magical things, when it comes to any Git operations such as cloning, fetching, pulling etc. all that's happening is we call Git on your behalf. In the case where there's less files than expected after doing a clone, for example, this is usually because there's something specific to the repository rather than SourceTree.

There's a couple of factors that come into play here:

- **Branches**: As others have pointed out in the comments already, make sure you're on the correct branch.
- **Ignored files**: There's actually three ignore files; local, global, and system. Whichever system that has 17,000 files would be the culprit as it wouldn't be checking in those files. Your pattern matching might be too general meaning it's applying to those 5,000 missing files.

  - local: In the main repository directory named `.gitignore`
  - global: `$HOME/.gitignore_global` (git 2.0 this has changed to `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`)
  - system: `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`

You can check which files have been ignored by either changing the file filter in SourceTree itself or using `git status --ignored` at the terminal to determine which files are being ignored. If you see any folder patterns this might be a big clue.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried checking the ignored files as you have told me but it still doesn't work. 

I have just another question: I have created a new repository in my computer. I have deleted all information in .gitignore from the first computer. Now I want to create a remote repository in the second computer from the first one (both computers in the same LAN). My question is why when I press pull, all the files are not downloaded? Because what I want to do is to work with this computer under the same branch. Could you please let me know how should I do it so I can achieve this?

Comment: Hey there. I think that should be created as a different question entirely - it's not really related to this part :)

Answer (score 0):

On the "Clone" page that shows up in Source Tree make sure you select the correct branch under "Advanced Options".

(It's set to master by default and you don't realize that because the dropdown is not down).

Oh. I realize that you're trying to fetch not clone. But people who're trying to clone also get redirected to this page so I'll leave this answer here.